# Linux: How to auto mount home for specific users from remote

Tags: centos, network-share, automount

I hope this question was not asked before, but I could not find something which really matches my problem.

Following scenario: We a park of 10 (or more) linux machines with the same user accounts (same uid). We want to assign each user to one machine, which should be his main machine, but he should still be able to work on other machines, but then automount the home from his main machine via nfs. What is the best way to achieve that?

I could specify the mount points for each user in `/etc/fstab` and mirror this on all machines, but I fear that becomes a bit annoying if the number of our users grows and a machine might be done for maintenance. Is there an elegant way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep it very simple, you can set the launch of mount command for each user (specifying its mount point) using the `~/.bashrc` file you can find in every user home folder.
A more elegant way to achieve that would be introducing configuration management software such as [Puppet](https://puppet.com) to manage system users, their grants, define specific behaviours and so on.